# Can I run Windows on a Macintosh (Mac Mini) computer as the default OS like any other PC?

Tags: windows, mac

**I do not want to use mac OS at all, I just like the hardware.**
I dont want to use Paralels or Boot Camp.
I think that it is possible because both Macintosh OS and Windows run on x86 or x64.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 (both 32 and 64 bit version ) can be installed natively on a Mac in **BIOS** mode on a **MBR** style disk.

Forget installing with BIOS mode on a GPT style disk, that only works in UEFI mode.

Since your mac mini comes with UEFI enabled by default, you will need to change this and you will need to change the format on the disk.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't install 64-bit Windows 7 in UEFI mode?

Comment: The older UEFI version on some (all?) mac mini's seems to limit this.